# Cannot send message successfully as a GUEST in Facebook customer chat plugin

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chat, facebook-customer-chat

After implement FB customer chat plugin using Gatsby, it can be shown on my website. However, the conversation for GUEST, indicate that "The message cannot be sent" for some reason, please have a look on the capture.

[image]

P/s: I can send message normally with logged in account conversation

Anyone know what is going wrong ? How can fix that ? Please advise me

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that Page settings > General > Messages is set to "People can contact my page privately"

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause, this is not about technical things, but relating to Page restriction that being attach to the plugin

Anyone got this issue, should go to Page settings > General > Make sure Country and Age is for ***Everyone***